# How to unit test arrow functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, ecmascript-6

I have this javascript class:

```
class SearchService {

    /*@ngInject*/
    constructor($log, $timeout) {
        this._log = $log;
        this._timeout = $timeout;
    }

    startSearch(value, updateCallBack) {
        this.startSearchPrj(updateCallBack);
    }

    startSearchPrj(updateCallBack) {
        chunkedRequest({
            url: 'http://localhost:9090',
            method: 'GET',
            chunkParser: (rawChunk, prevChunkSuffix = '') => {
                return [JSON.parse(rawChunk), prevChunkSuffix];
            },
            onChunk: (err, parsedChunk) => {
                var data = this.cleanResults(parsedChunk)
                if(!this.activeChunkId) {
                    this.activeChunkId = data.resultCategoryId;
                }
                this.searchResults[data.resultCategoryId] = data;
                updateCallBack();
            }
        });
    }

    ...

}

export default SearchService;
```

There is an arrow function for `onChunk` and I like to write a unit test with jasmin for it (since it will get much more complex soon). How can I do this?

I tried to refactor the class and moved the code into an onChunk method. But then `this` get's an other meaning and I cannot access the object data.

Comment: The obvious answer is to split it out into its own function (not a public one) and do `onChunk: (err, parsedChunk) => onChunk.call(this, err, parsedChunk)` or simply `onChunk: onChunk.bind(this)`, but hopefully there's a better answer than that!

Comment: What problem are you having unit testing this? If you can show the unit test code it might provide a more useful answer.

Comment: The same way as you would unit test any other function?

Answer (score 0):

For callback functions ES.next class properties (currently at [stage 1](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262)) is the way to go:

```
class SearchService {
    onChunk = (err, parsedChunk) => { ... };
    ...
        chunkedRequest({
            ...
            onChunk: this.onChunk
        });    
    ...
}
```

Which are just syntactic sugar over ES2015:

```
class SearchService {
    /*@ngInject*/
    constructor($log, $timeout) {
        this.onChunk = (err, parsedChunk) => { ... }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This way event handlers are exposed for testing and don't have to be encumbered with ES5-styled `Function.prototype.bind`.

Alternatively, prototype method instead of arrow property can be used in conjunction with bind operator (currently at [stage 0](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/05/14/function-bind)):

```
class SearchService {
    onChunk(err, parsedChunk) { ... };
    ...
        chunkedRequest({
            ...
            onChunk: ::this.onChunk
        });    
    ...
}
```

Which is sugared `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
            onChunk: this.onChunk.bind(this)
```

Comment: *"For callback functions ES7 class properties (currently at stage 1)"* If it's stage 1 then it's not ES7 (ES2016) ;) E2016 is already "closed" (no new features will be added).

Comment: @FelixKling This is ES6 == ES2015 equality that creates confusion. ES7 is *not* equal to ES2016. ES2016 is accepted standard. ES7 (ECMAScript 7, aka ES Next) is WIP, also a colloquial term to designate ES features that aren't parts of any standard.

Comment: I have never seen anybody from the committee using this term. When I asked about what they use for work-in-progress features, they said "ES next": https://twitter.com/fkling42/status/702905807583596544 . Since as you said that this can easily be confused, why not avoid it ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for clarification, good to know that they use 'next' thing back again

Comment: FYI, I was curious now what others think and created a Twitter poll: https://twitter.com/fkling42/status/729700943164399616. Not sure it gets much distribution, but we'll see :)

Comment: @FelixKling Nice, I will take a look at the results.